# I need to remove the spaces from a string input from console

Tags: java, arrays, string

so I have a console input in this format:

> "Adrian, 18, 180, 80"
>    And I used this which doesn't work

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
line = reader.readLine();
System.out.println("You added this user: " + line);
String[] b=line.split(",");
for(String name : b){
   name.replace(" ","");
   System.out.println(name);
   }
```

However, the output is the following:

```
Adi
 16
 180
 80
```

I have tried different methods but no one seems to work for me. Maybe it could be because I call it there into the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Notice how `replace`returns a `a string derived from this string` (quote from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))). That's because it doesn't change the value of the initial string. In Java String are immutable.

You have to either directly print the result of `replace` or assign it to a variable.

```
for(String name : b){
    name = name.replace(" ","");
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

or shorter:

```
for(String name : b){
    System.out.println(name.replace(" ",""));
}
```

Use `print` instead of `println`if you want to display the whole result on a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `String` is [Immutable](https://www.javatpoint.com/immutable-string), any modification should be assigned to a new `String`.

```
   String trimmed = name.replace(" ","");
   System.out.println(trimmed);
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is immutable, so when you call `replace`, you are not actually removing spaces from `name`, but just creating a new string with no reference to it. You can simply assign the `replace` return to `name`:

```
for (String name : b) {
   name = name.replace(" ","");
   System.out.print(name);
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to have the output in a single line, you should use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println` (as above). The latter adds a newline at the end of the input.

Comment: This does nothing. I need it to be without the spaces. Now it's printing "Adi 16 180 80" but it needs to print without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) of the String.replace() method we find the following: "Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar."

This means you have to save the result of name.replace(" ","") because the method doesn't change your old string. Try this:

```
name = name.replace(" ","");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use System.out.print() instead of System.out.println().

System.out.println() will place the cursor in the next line.